# onClick Link Outside of Map Using Mapped Values in JavaScript/React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dom-events

Mapping over values as follows in a React component:

```
const [showBttn, setShowBttn] = useState(false);

{info
  .map(infoDetails => (
    <div className='card' onClick={() => showBttn(true)}>
      <p>{infoDetails.text}</p>
    </div>
  ))}
```

I want to be able to click on each item and take the values of what's being mapped in the item and use it as a link for another part within component, that's show/hidden `onClick` of the element.

```
{showBttn && (
    <a
      href={
        URL + infoDetails.text
      }>
      <Button>My button</Button>
    </a>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a state to control this

```
const [infoSelected, setInfoSelected] = useState(false);

{
  info.map((infoDetails) => (
    <div
      className="card"
      onClick={() => {
        showBttn(true);
        setInfoSelected(infoDetails);
      }}
    >
      <p>{infoDetails.text}</p>
    </div>
  ));
}

{showBttn && (
    <a
      href={
        URL + infoSelected.text
      }>
      <Button>My button</Button>
    </a>
}
```